how to add an icon in Dismissible in flutter?
little question for you..
in this picture in my dismissible widget when i drag it to right or left it will delete the items of my list . but the word just  "Delete" isn't enough for me and i want to be trash icon next to my text also...
so what should i do ?
please help me.

unnecessary  i think but my code :
return Dismissible(
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      background: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        child: const Text(
                          'Delete',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onDismissed: (direction) async {
                        await deletePost(listpost![index].id.toString());
                        setState(() {
                          listpost!.removeAt(index);
                          fetchAllPosts().then((value) => listpost = value);
                        });
                      },


Whenever you want two widgets next to each other, horizontally, you may use a Row widget - it accepts multiple children:

return Dismissible(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  background: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    color: Colors.redAccent,
    child: Row( // Wrap with a row here
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        Icon(
          Icons.delete,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
       
        Text(
          'Delete',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  onDismissed: (direction) async {
    await deletePost(listpost![index].id.toString());
    setState(() {
      listpost!.removeAt(index);
      fetchAllPosts().then((value) => listpost = value);
    });
  },
);


omg .. i don't  know why i couldn't  find the the solution .. i knew what was row but it didn't came to my mind to use it in this case .. thank u so much

You can also use the TextButton.icon widget which adds an icon to a TextButton.
TextButton.icon(
  icon: Icon(
    Icons.delete,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  label: Text(
    'Delete',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ),
  onPressed: ...
)

